# Source code from URL

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to get the source code from url, to build an application in python. I used

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("http://www.google.com/")
print(html.code)
```

This returns me HTTP code (200)
What should I do to get the HTML code (contents in ' view source code' page)?

Comment: [HOWTO Fetch Internet Resources Using The urllib Package](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html)

Comment: I am new to Python, I suppose using read function,
print(html.read) should work, however, it errors out for other urls

Comment: Use try-except to handle errors

Comment: Try this:-  print(html.read())

Answer (score 2):

You have to use read method to get the source code.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("http://www.google.com/")
content = html.read()
print(content)
```